# Change the browser

Tags: html

How do I change the browser Color on my mobile device?`

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
</head>`
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What color are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add link in meta tag
`<meta name="theme-color" content="red">`